# ajaxUpload и мультизагрузка файлов

Tags: jquery, ajax

Можно ли настроить модуль ajaxUpload.js для поддержки мультизагрузки файлов?

Comment: Используйте [этот плагин](http://fineuploader.com/). Он поддерживает мультизагрузку.

Comment: @Deonis, плагин требует девять долларов за загрузку. ))

Comment: @Deus, этот @Deonis - он как бы намекает.

Comment: @istem, есть еще jQuery-File-Upload-jquery-ui. Но в нем чуть менее чем 9000 файлов, примочек, свистелок и перделок и весит все это где-то 260 кб. Чистить его от лишнего - трата времени и нервов. Будем создавать свой плагин!

Comment: @Deus, пробуйте [скачать отсюда](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader) (кнопка **ZIP**). Или вот, [прямая сылка](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader/archive/master.zip)

Comment: @Deonis, круто. Спасибо!

Comment: blueimp fileuploader есть же, особенно для картинок удобен